# How to concatenate dataframes and download as file without creating a tempory file first?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, streamlit

I build a `streamlit` app that needs to create a `csv` file in a very specific format. A minimal example looks like this:

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def main():
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(5, 4)))
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(5, 4)))
    df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(5, 4)))

    di = {'df1': df1, 'df2': df2, 'df3': df3}

    fn = 'export.csv'
    with open(fn, 'w+') as f:
        for k, v in di.items():
            f.write(f'{k}\n')
            v.to_csv(f, header=False, index=False)
            f.write('\n')

    with open(fn, 'rb') as file:
        st.download_button(
            'Download file',
            data=file,
            file_name=fn,
            mime='text/csv'
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

So, for this example it looks like this

[image]

While this works, I don't like that I first create a file which I need to store to later open it again.

How can I get the exact same output, but without creating this file first? I tried via string concatenation using `v.to_string()`, but then the output seems space separated and not comma separated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seems I was on the right track with the strings but I still needed `BytesIO`; this code seems to work now:

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import BytesIO


def main():
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(5, 4)))
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(5, 4)))
    df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(5, 4)))

    di = {'df1': df1, 'df2': df2, 'df3': df3}

    result_string = ""
    for key, df in di.items():
        result_string += f"{key}\n"
        result_string += df.to_csv(index=False, header=False)
        result_string += "\n"

    csv_bytes = BytesIO(result_string.encode())
    st.download_button(
        'Download file',
        data=csv_bytes,
        file_name='export.csv',
        mime='text/csv'
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```